# Is there an existing way to make blogs for nodes (not users)?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to be able to set up blogs (or blog-like things, anyway) on arbitrary nodes -- imagine that you have a content type representing an organization, and that organization's owner can create blog entries about the organzation, its activities, etc.  This would not be a lot of code to write, but I'd sure prefer to use an existing solution than hack a new one together.

Is there anything out there like that?  Any experiences to report about adapting/hijacking the existing blog module for this purpose?  Thanks!

Comment: if you dont need to allow other people to comment on the posts, you can use the built-in comment system of a node to create the blogs

Comment: that's about as simple at it gets, but if you want people to be able to comment and don't want the overhead of OG, you can easily create a system to manage this with only a few little modules like entity reference, etc. I have done this myself in lieu of OG because it is usually overkill for my needs

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit of a learning curve at first but you could use [OG Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) for something like this. Make your organization node be a group and add an audience field to blog content type.

Comment: Indeed; thanks for the comment.  I was thinking about that, but that seems like an awful lot of weight to add just for some simple blog-type things.  But, yes, it's an option.

Comment: Besides OG groups you could setup your own entity references, that's essentially what OG groups is doing but it may shed some of the extra weight from setting up something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach to "*... adapting/hijacking the existing blog module ...*", is to consider the [Enterprise Blog](https://www.drupal.org/project/enterprise_blog) module. From its project page:

> Enterprise Blog is a complete blog solution that borrows many features from Wordpress. It is designed to be a **replacement for the core blog module** and provide much greater features and customizations.
>
> Check out [OpenEnterprise](http://drupal.org/project/openenterprise) for a great distribution to install Enterprise Blog.

Should you want to consider using the Blog module instead, you may want to review the existing [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog) about it.

Comment: Thx -- I'll check it out.